# remove some elements from a matrix according to the indices

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I have a matrix:

```
a = ([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1]
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

and I want to print the 0s in the matrix but not all of the 0s. I only want to keep the 0s in every row with the smallest index and remove all subsequent zeros in the row.
For instance, in the first row of this matrix, the second element (`a[0][1]`) should be kept and the rest of elements in the first row should be deleted since they are all zeros.

I used `pop()` for 2D array but I got attribute error. And the output is not correct too. I don't know how to compare indices and select the smallest column index in every row.

This is my code:

```
for ix, row in enumerate(a):
  for iy, i in enumerate(row):
    if i==0 and (iy+ix<(iy+1)+ix) :
        a[ix].pop((iy+1))
        print(ix,iy)
    elif i==0 and (iy+ix>(iy+1)+ix):
        a[ix].pop(iy)
        print(ix,iy+1)
print(a)
```

my expected result is the set of indices and the modified matrix a.

```
0 1

1 0

2 0

3 1

a=[[1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,1],[1,0]]
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you include your expected result?

Comment: Sure. I edited the post. @MichaelSzczesny

Comment: Are you using numpy or no? Tags say one thing, code another...

Comment: Yes I use it. This code was only my though to find a way for getting the outputs. I tried numpy and even pandas too. I mentioned numpy in tags to ask any help with numpy or without. And now I am working on your numpy codes too for the other part of my program. It helped me alot. Thank you. @MadPhysicist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution only works if there is at least one zero in every row.

```
indices = []
for x,row in enumerate(a):
    i = row.index(0)
    indices.append((x,i))
    a[x] = row[:i+1] + [e for e in row[i:] if e]

print(indices)
print(a)
```

Output

```
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 1)]
[[1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
a = [[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]]

b = []
for i in a:
    f = False
    c = []
    for j in i:
        if (j==0 and f==False) or j != 0:
            c.append(j)
            if j == 0: f = True
        else:
            continue
    b.append(c)
```

output:

```
[[1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
```

For getting indices `zero` in array you can try this:

```
list({i : j.index(0) for i,j in enumerate(b)}.items())
# [(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you. But because this code is a part of a big program, I need indices too.

Comment: @exocytosis what do you mean that you say `you need indices`

Comment: In the question post, the expected output is included. I need  the indices of zeros in every row that has a smallest column.

Comment: @exocytosis i edit answer and add this line for you purpose : `list({i : j.index(0) for i,j in enumerate(b)}.items())`. is this your answer?

Comment: Yeah it is.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example input

`a = [[1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,1]]`

and the expected output
`>>[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 1)]`

you can reframe the problem as finding the index of the element in each row which has the value zero (and where more than one element exists, return the first).

By framing it this way, the solution is as simple as iterating through each row of `a` and retrieving the `index` of the value `0` (whereby only the first element will be returned by default).

Using list comprehension that would look like this:

```py
value_to_find = 0
desired_indexes = [
  row.index(value_to_find) for row in a
]
```

or using `map` that would be:

```py
value_to_find = 0
desired_indexes = map(lambda row:row.index(value_to_find), a)
```

Then you could enumerate them to pair the results with the row number

```py
enumerate(desired_indexes)
```

Et voila!
`>>[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 1)]`

The entire solution can be written in a single line like so:

```py
answer = list(enumerate(map(lambda row:row.index(0), a)))
```

Comment: @exocytosis - Isn't modifying matrix `a` a necessary part of your question?

Comment: Yeah definitely it was. It was necessary but I thought I cant have both outputs in the same time and I was thinking to other solutions to modify the matrix and unfortunately I couldn't do it. : ))  @MichaelSzczesny

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's a zero in every row, you can get its column index with

```
c = np.argmin(a, axis=1)
```

Alternatively, if the matrix can contain negative numbers, you can do

```
c = np.argmax(np.equal(a, 0), axis=1)
```

The rows are just

```
r = np.arange(len(a))
```

The result you want is then

```
result = np.stack((r, c), axis=-1)
```

If there are rows without a zero in them, you can filter the result with a mask:

```
mask = np.array(a)[r, c] == 0
result = result[mask, :]
```